# How to join two tables

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, forms

I have two two entities news and authors, and I also can to create news and authors. So when I create my news I want to display authors-list in my form "select"
[image]

After that I need to display it in my grid
[image]

The problem is that news are stored in table news but authors in table authors
Can somebody help mith it?

code

```
/**
 * Create table authors
 *
 */
$installer->getConnection()->dropTable($installer->getTable('tasknews/authors'));
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('tasknews/authors'))
    ->addColumn('authors_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
    ), 'Authors ID')
    ->addColumn('authors', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '255', array(
        'nullable'  => false,
    ))
    ->addColumn('created', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    ));
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);


/**
 * Create table news
 *
 */
$installer->getConnection()->dropTable($installer->getTable('tasknews/news'));
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('tasknews/news'))
    ->addColumn('news_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ))
//    ->addColumn('authors_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
//        'nullable'  => false,
//    ), 'Authors ID')
    ->addColumn('title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '255', array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ))
    ->addColumn('description', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ))
    ->addColumn('created', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    ))
    ->addColumn('is_active', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    'default'   => '1',
    ), 'Is Block Active');
//    ->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('tasknews/news', 'authors_id', 'tasknews/authors', 'authors_id'),
//        'authors_id', $installer->getTable('tasknews/authors'), 'authors_id',
//        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE);
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

Comment: Do you have the table definition? Could I see it?

Answer (score 2):

First, you article table must have a foreign key to the authors table.
Let's call it `author_id`.  I see you commented that in your table creation script.
In the article add/edit form you need this field for the author select

```
$authors = Mage::getModel('[module]/author')->getCollection();
$options = array();
foreach ($authors as $author) {
    $options[$author->getId()] = $author->getName(); //replace getName with a method that returns the author name.
}

$fieldset->addField('author_id', 'select', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('[module]')->__('Author'),
    'name'      => 'author_id',
    'required'  => true, //or false
    'options'   => $options,
));
```

And in your grid you can add the column like this

```
$authors = Mage::getModel('[module]/author')->getCollection();
$options = array();
foreach ($authors as $author) {
    $options[$author->getId()] = $author->getName(); //replace getName with a method that returns the author name.
}
$this->addColumn('author_id', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('[module]')->__('Author'),
    'index'     => 'author_id',
    'type'      => 'options',
    'options'   => $options,
));
```

In order to not duplicate the code that retrieves the authors you can wrap that in a method an use it.

Comment: When I use news.authors_id like FK to authors.authors_id I can`t create my news. I wrote my sql above

Comment: Plese help me with authors model

Comment: What to you mean you can't create news if you add the FK?

Comment: If i use foreign key (authors_id) in table news to table authors (authors_id) like I wrote above. I have an error(SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`news`, CONSTRAINT `FK_NEWS_AUTHORS_ID_AUTHORS_AUTHORS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`authors_id`) REFERENCES `authors` (`authors_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE))

Comment: This problem is solved if first create author and next create news

Comment: that's what I was about to suggest. Make sure that when you save an article, you also send an author id in the form. My answers should do just that.